# Is it possible to override the pipeline default image in a hidden job used as a template

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-pipelines

I’ve created a hidden job that requires a specific image:

**myhiddenjob.yml**

```
.dosomething:
  inherit:
    default: false
  image: curlimages/curl
  script: …
```

This job is used in a pipeline that has a different base image:

```
default:
  image: maven:3.8.6-jdk-11

include:
 - remote: 'https://myhiddenjob.yml’

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile

testjob:
  stage: mystage
  script:
    - echo "Working…"
    - !reference [.dosomething, script]
```

The default image provides the `mvn` command used in the build job. However I want that the `testjob` uses a different image, the one defined inside the hidden job (`curlimages/curl`). However, although I specified inherit false, my hidden job uses the default image (`maven:3.8.6-jdk-11`) instead of the specified (`curlimages/curl`).

How can I override it in the hidden job definition?

Comment: is it that only image needs to be changed in actual job compared to the hidden job.
or can there be other modifications. Can u specify the usecase

Comment: I updated the question to clear it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends)

```
.dosomething:
  image: curlimages/curl
  script: …

testjob:
  stage: mystage
  before_script:
     - .....testjob sepcific commands
  extends: .dosomething
```

You can also use `before_script` to add `testjob` specific commands.